# Warning: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

Tags: java, android, x86

I have been programming an App and now I have this warnings and the App screen on my device are WHITE. I have tested it on an virtual device and on an Huawei P8 little

These are the warnings:

```
    12-10 17:37:51.832 13864-13864/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    12-10 17:37:52.065 13864-13864/de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft-1/lib/x86
    12-10 17:37:52.099 13864-13864/de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10014
    12-10 17:37:52.247 13864-13864/de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    12-10 17:37:52.410 13864-13901/de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

This is the Android manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="de.httptgp_papenburg.tauchgemeinschaft">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="7"
            android:targetSdkVersion="26"
            tools:ignore="GradleOverrides" />
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
            android:icon="@mipmap/logo_tgp_original"
            android:label="@string/a"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_tgp_original_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/a"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
            <activity android:name=".Main4Activity" />

            <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" />
            <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" />

            <activity
                android:name=".Rating"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_rating"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
            <activity
                android:name=".Website"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_website"
                android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
        </application>    
    </manifest>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?